# Counting number of char in a string and creating another string with the same number of char

Tags: c#, string

So I want to be able to create a headline and underline it with for example an "=". However I want the number of "=" to match with the number of characters in the headline. Preferably I want to be able to do it with a for loop.

Here's what I have so far.

```
string headLine = "Example";
Console.WriteLine(headLine);

for (char i = '='; i <= headLine.Length; i += '=')
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: You can do it in your loop if you don't use WriteLine but Write - and change the weird loop to a simple `for (int i = 0; i<headLine.Length; i++)` (followed by a `Console.Write('=');`. However, you don't need a loop at all, you seem to be overthinking things a bit...

Comment: @oerkelens Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 7):

No need for any loops, just create a new string to your specifications:

```
string headLine = "Example";
Console.WriteLine(headLine);
Console.WriteLine(new string('=', headLine.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

your for loop is completely wrong, you are comparing a char which represents value with an int that represents length. Do something like this instead:

```
string headLine = "Example";
Console.WriteLine(headLine);
char c = '=';
for (int i=0; i < headLine.Length; i++) //from 0 to length-1 gives the full length
{
    Console.Write(c);
}
```